# Mezzanine: Editable tag inside header/footer template

Tags: django, mezzanine

I want to be able to use `{% editable something %}` inside of a layout template or a template that is included in various pages. For example a company slogan in the header or a text inside of page_menu.

I want to edit the value only on one place of administration (I don't want to have it duplicated over all pages models).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The `editable` template tag makes the content editable inline wherever it appears as well as in the admin. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @ken Yes, but the second parameter of editable is usually something like page.homepage.something, right? Where page is current page model instance. Where do I have to add the `something` to make it editable from one place in administration and accessible by all pages?

Comment: It can be any model instance, it's not specifically related to Page models.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, the `something` arg can be any model instance - so all you'll need it a template tag or possibly context processor for getting the instance into every template, then voila.